# Are there Graphviz (.dot) Linux viewers which show the tooltips?

Tags: linux, graphviz

Are there Graphviz (.dot) Linux viewers which show the tooltips given by `tooltip` attribute, or do I have to generate SVG file first?

Answer (score 0):

[ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html) shows tooltips as desired. Unfortunately it's quite slow for me.